# How do you stop unit cycling in Civilization V?

Tags: civilization-5

We did our first multiplayer Civ V LAN game (it was fun) yesterday, but the unit cycling is very, very, very annoying. Is there a way to make it stop? I searched the Internet and the answers are old and do not seem to have anything to do with current versions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's an option in the menu.

Options > Interface > Auto Unit Cycle

[image: screenshot of civ5 interface menu]

Comment: omg i wish i knew about this before, in all the time i put into Civ 5 this was the most annoying thing to deal with... +1

Comment: Yeah, it's one of the things I find most annoying too, I always have it turned off :)
And @Paralytic at least you know now :)